# Can selenium open a search result page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm new to selenium. I want to ask about if there's a easy way to open a search result page of some urls, not just the homepages.

for examples,
I search stack overflow in google. The url is here, but the return page is google homepage.Is it possible to get the result page directly? I want to scratch some result pages. If I just open the homepage then input the keywords to get the result pages, I think this way should be very slow.

Thank you for your answers.

```
from selenium import selenium
url ='http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=stack+overflow&aq=o&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai='
sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', url)
sel.start()
sel.open('/')
sel.wait_for_page_to_load(10000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code:

```
from selenium import selenium
url ='http://www.google.com/'
sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', url)
sel.start()
sel.open('/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=stack+overflow&aq=o&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=')
sel.wait_for_page_to_load(10000)
```

So your `url` is pointing to the start page and you do `open` what you need - the search result